# In SSR, What is the meaning of Server?

Tags: node.js

I just learned CSR and SSR. So CSR is rendered in browser and
SSR is rendered in server and gives it to browser.
I can understand what CSR means but in SSR, what is the server?
Is it a big database like AWS? or just small codes stuff in npm?
I can't understand exactly what server means.

Anybody could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, a server is just a computer with a program on it configured to respond to network requests. Often such a server's network configuration allows it to be reached from the public internet (with an IPv4 address and hostname). It can be as small or large as you want. You could use a hosted server (or hosted service provider) with a huge infrastructure like AWS; you could also use a spare computer lying around, install a backend on it (Node.js? Next.js? PHP? Etc...) and hook it up to your network, and it'll also function as a server.

There are also local development servers. These are pieces of software running on your local machine that allow *you*, the developer (and usually only you) to run server code while testing. These are usually accessible by plugging a localhost URL into your web browser, such as `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

In SSR, 'the server' is usually the web server which contains the HTML files, but it can also be a separate server, such as with bigger websites that may have dedicated file storage servers, and rendering servers. Either way, the server is always just a computer owned by the website owners, which sends stuff over when someone asks it to.